# How to ensure that an accordion tab is open at all times but only one at once

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I'm quite new to code (also new to stackoverflow so i apologise if the format of this question is slightly incorrect, I'm just getting my head round it). I have an accordion that is almost working as intended. It only has two tabs, and when the other tab is opened the current one is closed which is correct. However, I want to ensure that one of the tabs is open at all times and also by default when the page loads, so when the page loads the first tab is already open. If i click on the second then the first one closes and the second opens. If i then click on the second again, it stays open, as one has to be open at all times. At the minute, on page load they are both collapsed and can be collapsed if you click on the current open tab. Below is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function close_accordion_section() {
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
  }

  $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    if ($(e.target).is('.active')) {
      close_accordion_section();
    } else {
      close_accordion_section();
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion,
.accordion * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
}

.accordion-section-title {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #585858;
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

.accordion-section-title.active,
.accordion-section-title:hover {
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #585858;
}

.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.accordion-section-content {
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Accordion Section #1</a>

    <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
      <p>accordion 1 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Accordion Section #2</a>

    <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
      <p>accordion 2 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When document is ready add "open" and "active" class to first ".accordion-section-content" and ".accordion-section-title" elements respectively. 
Don't call "close_accordion_section()" function if clicked ".accordion-section-title" already has "active" class.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $($('.accordion .accordion-section-title')[0]).addClass('active');
    $($('.accordion .accordion-section-content')[0]).slideDown().addClass('open');

    function close_accordion_section() {
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }

    $('.accordion-section-title').click(function (e) {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        if ($(e.target).is('.active')) {
            //close_accordion_section();
        } else {
            close_accordion_section();
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open');
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.accordion,
.accordion * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
}

.accordion-section-title {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #585858;
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

.accordion-section-title.active,
.accordion-section-title:hover {
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #585858;
}

.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.accordion-section-content {
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Accordion Section #1</a>

    <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
      <p>accordion 1 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Accordion Section #2</a>

    <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
      <p>accordion 2 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer and just what i was looking for! Thankyou!

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this :

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
  active: 2
});
```

or

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

Instead of 2, you can pass any accordion panel id which you want to active in page load.

Pass it in document.ready.